# WSO2 - Identity server - Create service provider by tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Currently, i have a main super carbon where i configure my service providers (one per application) and i am able to login to my application using users from multiple tenants and it works fine.

However, in case i would like to configure a service provider (application) on tenant level, will it work? the reason it to have custom configuration by tenant and not to apply the same configuration on all tenants at once.

Doing this, will i loose the option to have a single login screen for all tenants ?

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 Identity Server, configuring service providers (applications) at a tenant level is possible and can be beneficial for achieving tenant-specific customizations.

Each tenant in WSO2 can have its own set of service providers.
Having tenant-specific service providers does not inherently mean losing the ability to have a single login screen for all tenants.
You can rebrand your login page however you want.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/rebranding/rebrand-login-pages-for-service-providers/#configure-the-login-page